# HTML table column of equal size

Tags: html, html-table

With the below code, I get the columns size being different (esp the last column is small) I would like to have all the three columns to be of same size.Thanks.

```
<html>
<body>
<h4>Two rows and three columns:</h4>
<table border="1" width="100%" height="400" align="top">
<tr style="height: 1">
  <td>
   <table width="100%" border="2" height ="100" align="top">
     <tr>
       <td>1-1</td>
       <td>1-2</td> 
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>1-3</td>
       <td>1-4</td>
     </tr>
   </table>
 </td> 
  <td>
   <table width="100%" border="2" height ="100" align="top">
     <tr>
       <td>2-1</td>
       <td>2-2</td> 
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>2-3</td>
       <td>2-4</td>
     </tr>
   </table>
<td>
   <table width="100%" border="2" height ="100" align="top">
     <tr>
       <td>3-1</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>     
       <td>3-2</td>
     </tr>
   </table>
 </td> 
</tr>
<tr style="vertical-align: top">
 </td> 
  <td>
   <table width="100%" border="2" height ="100">
     <tr>
       <td>4-1</td>
       <td>4-2</td> 
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>4-3</td>
       <td>4-4</td>
     </tr>
</table>
 <td>
   <table width="100%" border="2" height ="100">
     <tr>
       <td>5-1</td>
       <td>5-2</td> 
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>5-3</td>
       <td>5-4</td>
     </tr>
   </table>
<td> 
   <table width="100%" border="2" height ="100">
     <tr>
       <td>6-1</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>6-3</td>
     </tr>
   </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you try to define the width on the root `td` columns?

Comment: What does `style="height: 1"` mean?

Comment: style="height: 1" won't work. only 0 is allowed to be without an unit

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Insert a `colgroup` element in your table:

```
<table>
  <colgroup>
    <col style="width: 33%" />
    <col style="width: 33%" />
    <col style="width: 33%" />
  </colgroup>
  <tr>
...
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: So this works only for 3 columns ? If i want to have more columns then how to go about it ?

Comment: @m4n07 this works for every amount of columns. just append one `col` for every column needed and adjust the width accordingly.

Comment: As of now i have 7 cols, This may change , But i have to change my code whenever it changes. It will be better even if the cols change I should be able to proceed without making html changes.

Comment: @m4n07 then maybe you should add a piece of js code to insert the colgroup for you. i know of no way to do this with a variable number of columns.

Comment: Thanks Sirko ! I have another question ,Is it possible to add a bit of spacing between inner tables 1 and 2.

Comment: @m4n07 have you tried setting a `margin` on the inner tables or a `padding` on the surrounding `<td>` ?

Answer (score 3):

## Few fixes to consider

```
<table style="table-layout: fixed; width: 100%;"> <!- set table layout to fixed and width to full width -->
    <colgroup>
        <col style="width: auto" /> <!- takes the remaining space -->
        <col style="width: 33.3333%" /> <!- or use 33.3333% for all instead if you want to occupy full width -->
        <col style="width: 33.3333%" />
    </colgroup>
    <tr>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    ...
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just set each `<td>` of the first level table to `width="33%"`

Answer (score 0):

You could try to set your the width of your columns to be absolute, instead of relative:

```
< TD WIDTH=200>
```

Try looking at this [link](http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/tables/_TD_WIDTH.html).

Answer (score -2):

An alternative is to set the css width of the table to 100% e.g.

```
table { width:100% }
```

The cells should inherit this and be of equal size. That way you are more flexible to different numbers of columns.